# Check if object path exists in tree of objects

Tags: python

I have a tree of objects and I need to check that particular object contains specific branch of objects. For example:

```
def specificNodeHasTitle(specificNode):
    # something like this
    return specificNode.parent.parent.parent.header.title != None
```

Is there an elegant way to do this without throwing exception if needed attribute is missing?

Comment: PEP8 states that you shouldn't use the `!=` when dealing with the `None` type. In python there is actually only one instance of the `None` type in a script, so `is not None` or `is None` are preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as long as you don't need indexes of arrays in your path to the item.

```
def getIn(d, arraypath, default=None):
    if not d:
        return d 
    if not arraypath:
        return d
    else:
        return getIn(d.get(arraypath[0]), arraypath[1:], default) \
            if d.get(arraypath[0]) else default

getIn(specificNode,["parent", "parent", "parent", "header", "title"]) is not None
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `try..except`:

```
def specificNodeHasTitle(specificNode):
    try:
        return specificNode.parent.parent.parent.header.title is not None
    except AttributeError:
        # handle exception, for example
        return False
```

There is nothing wrong with raising exceptions, by the way. It is a normal part of Python programming. Using `try..except` is the way to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22865040/289011) provided by [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) is the best and the most pythonic, but I can't help trying to show the great capabilities of python and its [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr) method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864932/python-check-if-object-path-exists-in-tree-of-objects

class A(object):
  pass

class Header(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.title = "Hello"

specificNode=A()
specificNode.parent = A()
specificNode.parent.parent = A()
specificNode.parent.parent.parent = A()
specificNode.parent.parent.parent.header = Header()

hierarchy1="parent.parent.parent.header.title"
hierarchy2="parent.parent.parent.parent.header.title"

tmp = specificNode
for attr in hierarchy1.split('.'):
  try:
    tmp = getattr(tmp, attr)
  except AttributeError:
    print "Ouch... nopes"
    break
else:
  print "Yeeeps. %s" % tmp


tmp = specificNode
for attr in hierarchy2.split('.'):
  try:
    tmp = getattr(tmp, attr)
  except AttributeError:
    print "Ouch... nopes"
    break
else:
  print "Yeeeps. %s" % tmp
```

That outputs:

```
Yeeeps. Hello
Ouch... nopes
```

Python's great **:)**